# Can software able to wrap gzip/gunzip around to preserve file ownership?

Tags: linux, perl, unit-testing

gzip/gunzip are found to change inode number, thus ownership are not preserved if opened by another owner.

`soluion posted by OP since thread is closed prematurely`

`Here is the solution to keep ownership, if anyone interested.`

`I modified the procedures, it passed the current basic tests.`

```
# the original file information
ok 1 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz Found
ok 2 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz -- fileowner <504>
ok 3 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz -- inode <692254>

# copy file to /tmp, processed by uid 500
***cp -vf /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz /tmp
`/shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz' -> `/tmp/colourbar.nii.gz'
***gunzip -f /tmp/colourbar.nii.gz
***gzip -f /tmp/colourbar.nii
ok 4 - /tmp/colourbar.nii.gz -- fileowner <500>
ok 5 - /tmp/colourbar.nii.gz -- inode <31>


# copy back to overwrite, and the ownership preserved
***cp -vf /tmp/colourbar.nii.gz /shared/shared
`/tmp/colourbar.nii.gz' -> `/shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz'
ok 6 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz -- fileowner <504>
ok 7 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz -- inode <692254>
```

Unit Test failed due to a feature in gzip/gunzip utility.
The discussion about gzip/gunzip is all over, I want to push a little further

Real problem need a real solution.
Can we get around to have the same fileowner on test6?

The original owner has uid 500, pass all unit tests

```
ok 1 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz Found
ok 2 - original fileowner <500>
ok 3 - original inode<692254>
gunzip -f /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz
ok 4 - fileowner after gunzip <500>
ok 5 - inode after gunzip<692255>
gzip -f /shared/shared/colourbar.nii
ok 6 - fileowner after gzip <500>
ok 7 - inode after gzip<692254>
```

Joe has uid of 504, test 6 failed

```
ok 1 - /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz Found
ok 2 - original fileowner <500>
ok 3 - original inode<692254>
gunzip -f /shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz
not ok 4 - fileowner after gunzip <504>
ok 5 - inode after gunzip<692255>
gzip -f /shared/shared/colourbar.nii
not ok 6 - fileowner after gzip <504>
ok 7 - inode after gzip<692254>
```

The original test script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More ;
return 1  unless $0 eq __FILE__;
main(@ARGV) if $0 eq __FILE__;
sub mock_gzip{
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $cmd = "gzip -f $file";
    print "$cmd\n";
    system($cmd);
}
sub mock_gunzip{
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $cmd = "gunzip -f $file";
    print "$cmd\n";
    system($cmd);
}
sub fileowner{
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $uid = `stat -c %u $file`;
    chomp($uid);
    return $uid;
}
sub get_inode{
    my $file =$_[0];
    my $inode = `stat -c %i $file`;
    chomp($inode);
    return  $inode;
}
sub main{
    #simulate real life situation - user A
    my $file = "/shared/shared/colourbar.nii.gz";
    my $fileu = $file;
    $fileu =~ s/.gz$//g;
    ok(-e $file,"$file Found\n");
    my $fileowner = fileowner($file);
    ok($fileowner>0,"original fileowner <$fileowner>\n");
    my $inode  = get_inode($file);
    ok($inode>0,"original inode<$inode>\n");

    # user B - gunzip/gzip owner changed
    mock_gunzip($file);
    my $fileowner_gunzip = fileowner($fileu);
    ok($fileowner_gunzip==$fileowner,"fileowner after gunzip <$fileowner_gunzip>\n");
    my $inode_gunzip  = get_inode($fileu);
    ok($inode_gunzip>0,"inode after gunzip<$inode_gunzip>\n");

    mock_gzip($fileu);
    my $fileowner_gzip = fileowner($file);
    ok($fileowner_gzip==$fileowner,"fileowner after gzip <$fileowner_gzip>\n");
    my $inode_gzip  = get_inode($file);
    ok($inode_gzip==$inode,"inode after gzip<$inode_gzip>\n");

    # solution, or verified no solution to be decided

}
```

Comment: The original owner of any file should remain intact after the filename/contents change. Unless you use the `chown` command, the owner will remain the same.

Comment: weird, most cases, whoever did the name and content change, became the new owner. chown was not used at all.

Comment: Maybe you should discuss some background info on your question. Are you running a server? If so, depending on where the file is located it can be taken over by a user. If it's in the root file system, then you may have had a security breach.

Comment: it is a common NFS shared directories by a group, all have read write permision on shared direcctory. I will try to update the quesiton in more detail as you mentioned.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - it seems like it may be a better fit for the Unix/Linux stack exchange.

Comment: Please review and lift the hold, as I changed according to spec, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you zip the file, you create a new file, and that is owned by the current user. Use the `-i` option to show the file's inode.

> robert:~> touch test
>
> robert:~> ls -li test
>
> 93644038 -rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 0 Dec 26 20:42 test

If you zip in place, the old file gets deleted, so it looks like it could replace the file, but it did in fact create a new one.

> robert:~> gzip test
>
> robert:~> ls -li test*
>
> 93644048 -rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 25 Dec 26 20:42 test.gz

When you unzip, you also create new files, again, owned by the current user.

> robert:~> gunzip test.gz
>
> robert:~> ls -li test*
>
> 93644052 -rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 0 Dec 26 20:42 test

So your error is to assume it's the same file, which it is not --- note the changing inode number in the beginning of the `ls` output. If it  tried to use the same inode, what would it do for archives with multiple files?

If you just rename the file, it is the same file and ownership is preserved:

> robert:~> sudo mv test renamed
>
> robert:~> ls -li renamed
>
> 93644052 -rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 0 Dec 26 20:42 renamed

Same for appending (changing contents):

> robert:~> sudo echo ... >> renamed
>
> robert:~> ls -li renamed
>
> 93644052 -rw-r--r-- 1 robert staff 4 Dec 26 20:51 renamed

See [Wikipedia on inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for more details on inodes.

Answer (score 1):

The gzip format doesn't preserve the owner. Furthermore, only root can set the ownership of a file to a different user.

You can use `tar` to record the owner of a file along with the file contents:

```
:; echo hello > sym2.txt
:; ls -l sym2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mayoff  staff  6 Dec 26 20:46 sym2.txt
:; tar cvzf sym2.tar.gz sym2.txt 
a sym2.txt
:; tar tvf sym2.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  0 mayoff staff       6 Dec 26 20:46 sym2.txt
```

To extract the tar file and preserve ownership, you need do so as root:

```
sudo tar xvf sym2.tar.gz
```

Alternatively, you can just extract the tar file while running as the user that should own the extracted files.

Comment: you are right  about when tar.gz lose ownership, tar is an option to look for  original owner. thanks